# Rails Custom Validation With Request Params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails noob ,

I am trying to write a custom validation but I am dependent on parameters that come from the post request. This example is similar to what I have - in this post model I want to validate that a user didn't already post on some topic, but to do that I have to have the topic id from the post request:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
...
   validate :user_already_posted, on: :create
   def user_already_posted
       topic=Topic.where(id: params[:topicId]).first
       //some code that runs on topic users and makes sure the user hasn't posted there
```

However , I learned that params isn't global and models can't access it (I last used laravel where this isn't the case , so it's confusing for me).
Are custom validations not suited for what I need ? do I need to look at filters or have the controller run a validating function of it's own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having a bit of a design problem here. You are creating a `post` validator, but the validation itself is not about the `post` instance. I mean, the model validator must evaluate all of the `post` attributes, using the default validators built-in `ActiveRecord` or creating custom ones, like you did, acessing the attributes via `self`.
I believe a `class method` receiving all your parameters and checking the conditions of the `post` creation is more clear:

**Class method on the model**

```
def self.user_already_posted(topic_id, user_id)
  # Do your thing
end
```

**Usage on the controller**

```
can_create = Post.user_already_posted(params[:topic_id], params[:user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: :topic_id
```

May not be exactly what you need, but the point is that you can validate within a scope.
You can also pass an array to validate on multiple parameters.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: [:topic_id, :post_id]
```